# Calculate Button Not outputting all numbers

Tags: java, defaultlistmodel

I am trying to code my Calculate button to output the Future Value into the List Model by year. I need to "Modify the actionPerformed event for the Calculate Button so that instead of calculating a single value, it calculated the future value for each year up tp the year selected via the combo box and adds a string showing the calculation for each year to the list." Right now it runs great, but skips the first year and outputs the second year as 0$.

```
private void calculateButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)      {
if (isValidData())
{
double p = Double.parseDouble(monthlyPaymentTextField.getText());
double r = Double.parseDouble(yearlyRateTextField.getText());
int y = numberofyears.getSelectedIndex();

NumberFormat currency = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
DefaultListModel alm = new DefaultListModel();
jList1.setModel(alm);
for(int i = 0; i < y; i++)
{
double fv = FinancialCalculations.calculateFutureValue(p, r, i);
alm.addElement(currency.format(fv));
}   

}
}
```

Here is the Financial Calculations code if it will help:

```
package murach.business;

public class FinancialCalculations
{
public static final int MONTHS_IN_YEAR = 12;

public static double calculateFutureValue(double monthlyPayment,
double yearlyInterestRate, int years)
{
int months = years * MONTHS_IN_YEAR;
double monthlyInterestRate = yearlyInterestRate/MONTHS_IN_YEAR/100;
double futureValue = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= months; i++)
{
futureValue = (futureValue + monthlyPayment) *
(1 + monthlyInterestRate);
}
return futureValue;
}
}
```

Comment: What specific section of code are you having a problem with? This looks like a general framework that your professor provided you with; what have you done with it thus far?

Comment: The calculateButtonActionPerformed. I need to change the code so that it will output the future value for each year into the List Model. It was set up to only output one answer in the beginning. I am just not sure how to code it to output the correct info to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the DefaultListModel to a variable, then use jList1.setModel on the variable. In the calculate function, then update the DefaultListModel variable instead of jList1.

So something like:

```
DefaultListModel alm = new DefaultListModel(...);
jList1.setModel(alm);
alm.addElement(...);
```

Comment: So where should I put the AbstractListModel? It will not let me put it in the calculate button part.

Comment: It can be added with the other variables at the bottom, then initialize it and jList.setModel in the calculate code.

Comment: Small error on my part, you can't instantiate AbstractListModel... change it to DefaultListModel.

Comment: Okay I got it to output the number on the list model. Now I need it to break the answer down by year. It is only outputting the single year.

Comment: Check the values of your for loop in the calculate function. It displays multiple values for me starting at 3 years.

Comment: I can't find where the for loop in not correct. I updated my code in the post I made so you can see what I have now.

Comment: Take the DefaultListModel and jList1.setModel out of the for loop so they aren't being reassigned. That should correct it from only displaying one element.

Comment: Perfect. Now I just need to figure out why it is not showing a number for one year and why the second year is $0.